# How to save formula value as text (automatically, via a formula)

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Spreadsheets - I'm looking for a simple way to convert formula value into text right after the formula has been used. And it shouldn't need any involvement from me - would need it to be automatic.

Maybe **replace the formula with its value right after the formula is done** or just **copy the result of the formula to another cell as text**.

Basically I just need the formula to run **only once** and keep the result without launching again after a refresh. Doesn't really matter which formula we're talking about.

Options?

Comment: possible only with script

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script running under an `onEdit` trigger (accessible using **Tools -> Script Editor**):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getFormula()) {
    e.range.setValue(e.range.getValue());
  }
}
```

This **replaces** the formula with its computed value, and would replace only the top-left cell for formulas that return multiple values like `QUERY` or `ARRAYFORMULA`.

**How to setup:**

1. `Save` the script and `Run` the script once. You should get an error `TypeError` that you can ignore.
2. The script should then trigger for any user edit you do in a cell.